# Selenium WebDriver: is it possible to test WebExtension that inject code to the current page?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, firefox-addon-webextensions, sikuli

I found [articles](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/6-easy-steps-testing-your-chrome-extension-selenium-eliran-shani) about opening browser extension as a page - but my extension inject JS to the current page - and extension can not inject code to `chrome*` pages. My only choice is [SikuliX](https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX1)? Also with SikuliX I can test the **badge** of my button. I think that with SikuliX I simulate real user behaviour - such tests about UI interactions looks like more robust for me. Also nice to test CSS correctness.

I tried to setup a hotkey for my extension:
[image: chromium keyboard shortcut for extension]

But
`driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'I')` (Python) or `driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "I")` (Java) 
do nothing, but I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and I see popup-UI opened.

UPDATE: I tried to use [pyautogui](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui) for mouse clicking - but even with opened extension popup UI `driver.window_handles` does not include it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, I test my extension by comparing expected and actual **screenshots**, using Selenium web driver, [pyautogui](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui) (for interactions with extension) and [opencv2](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python) (for computer vision), see more at https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/15/python-compare-two-images/

Answer (score 0):

You can configure webdriver to load your extension in to the browser while launching as well. Once your extension in loaded , it can inject required code that i am assuming makes some changes to html such as adding / removing some html elements or applying some styles which can be then tested using Selenium. You can also execute javascript using selenium.

Sikuli framework is based on image recognition and then simulating user interactions on it using mouse and keyboard . Your test cases might break under these scenarios :

- Change in resolution which may even result in layout changes
- Change in theme of the application resulting in color changes of ui-elements
- It will require focus ,etc.

Comment: Through the webdriver can I open the UI ("popup") of the extension, "click" to the button and check state of the "usual" opened current page?

Comment: I am not sure about extension page automation using webdriver... Will have to give it a try.